# How to replace a set of search/replace pairs?

Tags: perl

I have a dictionary of translations as a hash:

```
my %dict = { hello => 'hola', goodbye => 'adios' , ... }
```

(The actual use-case is not a human language translation! I'm replacing a load of tokens with some other values. This is just for example.)

How can I apply each of these to a string? Obviously I could loop them and pass each to `s/$key/$value/` but then I'd have to quote them so it wouldn't break if a search or replacement had (for example) `/` in it.

In PHP there's `strtr($subject, $replacement_pairs_array)` - is there anything similar in Perl?

Comment: perl is not as stupid as php, `s/$key/$value/` when `$key` is `/` and `$value` is `%` will swap `/` for `%`

Comment: `s/$_/$dict{$_}/ for keys %dict;` is the shortest clear way of doing it.

Comment: @user1937198 yes, but if $key is '(' then perl gets very unhappy. see amon's answer below. PHP's strtr is not a regexp-based thing, so it doesn't need this quoting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, your hash initialization is off: A hash is initialized as a list:

```
my %dict = ( hello => 'hola', goodbye => 'adios' , ... );
```

Or you can use a hash reference:

```
my $dict = { hello => 'hola', goodbye => 'adios' , ... };
```

which is a scalar.

Replacing the keys with the values in a string is easy:

```
s/$_/$dict{$_}/g for keys %dict;
```

unless

- The contents of substitutions shall not be replaced, e.g. `%dict = (a => b, b => c)` should transform `"ab"` to `"bc"` (not to `"cc"` as the above solution may or may not do, hash order is random).
- The keys can contain regex metacharacters like `.`, `+`, or `()`. This can be circumvented by escaping regex metacharacters with the `quotemeta` function.

The traditional approach is to build a regex that matches all keys:

```
my $keys_regex = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %dict;
```

Then:

```
$string =~ s/($keys_regex)/$dict{$1}/g;
```

which solves all these issues.

In the regex building code, we first escape all keys with `map quotemeta`, and then join the strings with `|` to build the regex that matches all keys. The resulting regex is quite efficient.

This guarantees that each part of the string is only translated once.

Comment: Wow! thank you for such an informative answer! (yeah, sorry 'bout the hash thing, obv this is not real code..)

Comment: I usually transform keys regex into regex `$keys_regex = qr/($keys_regex)/` to ensure regex will be compiled only once even if `s/$keys_regex/$dict{$1}/g;` used multiple times. BTW it has interesting performance features. `$keys_regex` will be transformed into Aho-Corasick trie and have linear search time. It is fast as hell.

Answer (score 3):

```
%dict = ( 'hello' => 'hola', 'goodbye' => 'adios' );
my $x="hello bob, goodbye sue";
my $r=join("|",keys %dict);
$x=~s/($r)/$dict{$1}/ge;
print $x;
```

This shows one way to do it.

Convert the hash keys to a alternated regexp ie "hello|goodbye", look for matches with that expression then use the found key to lookup the value in the hash.  With the g flag the regexp is globally or repeatedly applied to the string and the with e flag the replacement expression is evaluated as perl instead of being a literal replacement

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a [CPAN module](http://search.cpan.org/~kudarasp/PHP-Strings-0.28/Strings.pm#strtr) that'll do this