# Regular Expression: Replace values according to a translation table

Tags: regex, replace, mariadb

How can I replace a list of values like

```
married
single
non
married
couple
```

to a list like this using a regular expression

```
Status 2
Status 1
non
Status 2
couple
```

? I know can match each group by something like this

```
/(married|single)/gm
```

and that I can address the matched group by `$1`, `$2`, ... . But how can I address and/or if-else the group-value in the replace-part to acutally translate the values?

**Edit**

Let's say I have the values to replace in a MariaDB-colum `marital` in `myTable`. Then I can do something like

```
SELECT 
marital,
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(marital,
  "married", "Status 2")
, "single", "Status 1")
FROM myTable
```

To get the desired result. But Is there a way to do this with just one `REGEXP_REPLACE`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it woudn't be possible through regex alone. Which lang or tool you're running?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: I would love to do this in MariaDBs `REGEXP_REPLACE` but am looking for a more general solution, too.

Comment: This is not a problem for which regex is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with a single REGEXP_REPLACE because MariaDB doesn't support the required features in the third parameter.

You may do it using PHP with arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
or with callback: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

You may do it using Perl: [How to replace a set of search/replace pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596917/how-to-replace-a-set-of-search-replace-pairs?answertab=votes#tab-top)